# ansible test fails because lookup('file', '/path/to/file') returns old content, in gitlab-ci

Tags: python, docker, ansible, gitlab-ci

I wrote some ansible tests, using the assert module. The real task changes a file, the test reads it's content and checks if it contains some string.

Everything works fine on an normal VM (ubuntu EC2 instance). However, it fails in gitlab-ci in a docker container. Please bear with me if I sound confused. I am confused.

The main task and the debugging task look like this:

```
- name: Disable core dumps
  become: true
  pam_limits: 
    comment: " disable core dumps"
    domain: '*'
    limit_item: core
    limit_type: hard
    value: 0

- name: debug file content
  become: true
  vars:
     contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/security/limits.conf') }}"
  debug:
    var: contents
```

Checking the debug output, I can see that my line `*  hard core 0` is not in the contents variable. Consequently, a check like this fails:

```
 name: Assert that the line "* hard core 0" is in limits.conf
  become: true
  vars:
     contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/etc/security/limits.conf') }}"
  assert:
    that:
       contents is search('[^#][*]\s+hard\s+core\s+0.*')
```

However, this check succeeds:

```
- name: Get line with core configuration in limits.conf
  shell: grep -o -E '^\*\s+hard\s+core\s+0.*$' /etc/security/limits.conf
  register: core_line
```

The issue really seems to be that the file lookup doesn't see the file that the others see, the others being humans logging onto the machine, or the grep command.

Again, on a VM the file content is correct and the test succeeds, as expected. However, gitlab-ci spins up some docker container (which seems to be standard) and some virtual machine (which is special to this environment - in this case you won't be able to help me and I apologize for bothering you). Somewhere on the way things get weird, and I get confused

This is *not* an issue with the pam_limits module. It works just fine. The same happens when I use the lineinfile module.

The ansible version is ansible 2.6.4, python 2.7.6, GitLab Community Edition 10.8.7

Comment: Where do you expect file lookup to run?

Comment: You are right, that is the issue. I assumed is runs remotely on the controlled node, while it does run locally on the controlling node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookups are performed on ansible host (the host where ansible-playbook binary has been executed). Contrary, modules are executed on targeted host, (`hosts: foobar` statement in a play).

If you want to use data from the remote host, you can use `fetch`, or just `command: cat` (`command: grep`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, not so mysterious after all. How stupid of me - a careless false assumption in the beginning led me far down a wrong road. In my test, I ran ansible against localhost. I won't forget these lessons.